# Obsolete App on App Store and promote another App

Tags: android, ios

I have two application on app store, e.g A.0 & B.0. None of them contains apple push notification service.  I have merged application A.0 into application B.0 and given it a new version number B.1 .  I want to obsolete application A.0 permanently from the app store.

**And now I want to force the existing users to update or install application B.1 , who have already install the application B.0 and A.0  . *So, is there any way to do this?***

Comment: Do any one have any answer?

Comment: As per e-B below; there's no automatic way to do this — nothing as simple as going to iTunes Connect and saying that product X is the update for product Y. Customer coercion is all there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a magic solution but you have:

- add explanations in your Appstore app presentation text to let your users know the new app is available.
- add a review of your app that says you have a new version of your app.
- build a new version of the A app with a local notification that links to your new app Appstore download page. And in the "what's new in this version" text add the presentation of your new app. By the way, it will only works for those who update your A app.
- don't know how works your app but if you have remote feeds to dislay content you can change this content to send a message.

No other solution found.

Hope this helps.